# Does ConfidentialClientApplication have a common cache for all instances?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-ad-msal

There is an example on how to acquire token for client credentials with MSAL [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows#code-snippet). E.g.

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
    .WithAuthority(authority)
    .WithCertificate(certificate)
    .Build();
```

Now this will create a new `ConfidentialClientApplication` each time, so I am wondering if the token cache inside will be shared?

I use it for KeyVault integration and authority comes from the key vault callback so I cannot compose `ConfidentialClientApplication` beforehand, so I am wondering if it's ok to do that every time, or then cache will be useless?

Alternatively I will have to remember instances of `ConfidentialClientApplication` per authority myself using some kind of lazy initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer myself, it is apparently very easy: I just did call two different `ConfidentialClientApplication` and compared tokens and they were different.

Also turned off network and the second cache call failed.

So that definitely means there is no shared cache involved.

Comment: It actually depends where you are storing the cache. If it is per session, so then you are right about the difference. However, in memory or SQL storage will share the same cache.